# SQL Developer reports and external CSV file

Tags: sql, csv, join

I am noob and don’t have basic knowledge of any programming language. I`ll describe my situation and maybe someone can give me direction in what I should look further.

In my work I sometimes need get some statistics and compare large data files. To do this job our employer provided us with Oracle Discoverer Plus, problem is that I am not allowed to define joins or create new items, only supporting company can do this and to get for example new join I can sometimes wait for week. To resolve this situation I started to export CSV files and import them to MS ACCESS, because there I can write joins whatever I need in JetSql.  Recently our employer provides us access to SQL developer ‘in viewer mode’ now I am writing queries in SQL Developer Worksheet or save them as Report, for example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  PT.REQUEST_NUMBER, GIS_INFO.PROVINCE_ID, LEAST(SUM(CASE WHEN PT.LAND_A  < 0.3 THEN NULL ELSE PT.LAND_A  END) OVER(PARTITION BY PT.REQUEST_NUMBER ),SUM(CASE WHEN PT.LAND_B < 0.3 THEN NULL ELSE PT.LAND_B END) OVER(PARTITION BY PT.REQUEST_NUMBER )) AS ZZ FROM SELECT REQUEST.REQUEST_NUMBER, FIELDS.SEQ,FIELDS.LAND_A, FIELDS.LAND_B, FIELDS.BRC_ID FROM REQUEST LEFT OUTER JOIN FIELDS ON REQUEST.ID = FIELDS.B_ID WHERE REQUEST.PRI_ID = '199' AND REQUEST.STATUS NOT IN ('RECALLED', 'REJECTED') AND FIELDS.STATUS = 'ACTIVE') PT LEFT OUTER JOIN GIS_INFO ON PT.BRC_ID=GIS_INFO.BRC_ID WHERE GIS_INFO.PROVINCE_ID = 10001245 AND GIS_INFO.PRI_ID = '199'
```

Questions:

1. Sometimes I need to join my SQL Developer Report to CSV file what is on my desktop (now I am again importing them to MS ACCESS and joining there) but maybe there is possibility to somehow connect with SQL Developer to this CSV file?
2. Is there possibility to join one Report with another my created saved Report, so I should not copy all the long code every time?
3. Maybe I am using wrong software for my job?

Answer (score 0):

if you have the data in CSV and if you have access to SQL Server Management Studio.

**1) you can use Import/Export wizard to copy the data into a database by creating a table for it.
2) use this table for connecting your report, you can query your joins and tables using SQL server management studio.**